# Convert HTML DOM Collection to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

A couple group of "dl" lists:

```
<div class = "container">
   <dl class = "list">
       <dt class = "title">title 1-1</dt>
       <dd class = "detail">detail 1-1</dd>

       <dt class = "title">title 1-2</dt>
       <dd class = "detail">detail 1-2</dd>
   </dl>
</div>

<div class = "container">
   <dl class = "list">
       <dt class = "title">title 2-1</dt>
       <dd class = "detail">detail 2-1</dd>

       <dt class = "title">title 2-2</dt>
       <dd class = "detail">detail 2-2</dd>
   </dl>
</div>
```

I need to access all titles in 'dt' tags. the nodelist returned two nodes, but once I convert it to an array, it shows nothing in console.log.

```
var myContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

for(var i=0; i<myContainer.length; i++) {
    var nodelist = myContainer[i].getElementsByTagName('dt');

    console.log(nodelist);   //returns HTMLcollection []
                             // 0 - dt.title
                             // 1 - dt.title

    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist, 0);

    console.log(arr);        //returns []
                             //there are no child objects.
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: hmm... it works in chrome (Edit: and firefox). http://jsfiddle.net/EQGT8/ though isn't the first argument of `Array.prototype.slice` required?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Firefox 18.0.1. I haven't tested in other browsers.

Comment: @user1824996 Does KevinB's fiddle work for you? I'm using Firefox 18 as well and his fiddle works fine.

Comment: I can see the jsfiddle works but I don't understand why my real code doesn't work. I have spent quite a few hours on this issue before raising the question, and don't appreciate someone down vote me for no reason. If this is because I haven't tested in other browsers, then what's the point when I couldn't even fix the problem in firefox?

Comment: @Ian, KevinB What do you mean with "works fine"? It doesn't show the titles in the console.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Sure it does. This is what my console outputs: `HTMLCollection { 0=dt.title, 1=dt.title, length=2 } [dt.title, dt.title]`

Comment: @Ian Which confirms my assumption. It shows *dt.title*, but *not* the title. See my answer and the links.

Comment: I believe KevinB shows the correct information however I have a feeling why my actual code didn't show anything was because of the timing issue from getJSON cross-domain call. I am working on a callback function to test if my assumption is right. Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: @Ian, KevinB My apologies, you were on the right track.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I don't think you understand what is expected of the code. What the `console` _should_ print is the list of elements...and that's what it prints. If you want to get the `title`, you have to click on one of them in the console (for visual reasons), or access them by looping through the new array, `arr`. The code in the question and the code in the fiddle simple logs the array, it's not expected to log the `title`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche No problem, it's a confusing situation :)

Answer (score -1):

[`nodelist (HTMLCollection)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection) is not an array. See also [Why can't I use forEach or map on a NodeList?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList#Why_can%27t_I_use_forEach_or_map_on_a_NodeList.3F)

> NodeList are used very much like arrays and it would be tempting to use Array.prototype methods on them. This is, however, impossible.

Access it with

```
for (var j = 0; j < nodelist.length; j++)
    console.log(nodelist[j].innerHTML);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94ALa/)

Since this is also tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

```
$('.container .title').each(function(index, title) {
    console.log($(title).text());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6nRm/)

*Update*:

I finally found the culprit

Add at the end of the for loop

```
var titles = arr.map(function(dt) { return dt.innerHTML; });
console.log(titles);
```

this shows the `dt.title`'s text

```
["title 1-1", "title 1-2"]
["title 2-1", "title 2-2"]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSyMP/)